# Can someone explain the use of CQL_Filter Within in geoserver

Tags: javascript, cql, geoserver

I am trying to query for every states inside a geoid thus the use of WITHIN but it doesn't seem to work properly. Can you provide me a good example of it. The docs don't seem to be very good for CQL filters.
I am using following

```
"CQL_FILTER=WITHIN(the_geom,buffer( querySingle('"+
this.geoopts.lastLayer+"','the_geom','CODE=" +
this.geoopts.lastId + "') ,0.0001) )"
```

Comment: in this context what is a "geoid"?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you might be trying to use the 'querylayer' extension (1).  Do you have it installed?

Your CQL does look reasonable (for more details check out link 2 below).

As a note, the buffer function acts on the geometry directly.  As such, the only units which can be used are those from the coordinate reference system (CRS) of the first layer.

If that layer's CRS is the one for longitude / latitude, you are set.  A distance of 0.0001 is about 10 meters.

Given all that, things could easily be wrong if A) the querylayer plugin isn't installed or B) the CRS for the first layer is in meters.

1. Docs for the querylayer extension [http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/querylayer/index.html].
2. A little more about spatial predicates in (E)CQL [http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html#geometric-filters].